# Replace a div with jQuery and Ajax For Login

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, loading

I am just looking for a jQuery plugin that do replace a div, when login is a success. I did search many times at google, but i can't find ideal plugin, what i want to have. Do anyone of u know a plugin what i am searching? As a example i show:

```
<div class="box">
<form action="login.php" method="post">
Username:
<input type="text" name="username">
Password:
<input type="text" name="password">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
</div>
```

What i want to replace a div that have a class="box" is:

```
<div class="box" style="display: none; height: 100px;"> <p><img src="/loading.gif" alt="" align="left" /><strong>Logged in...</strong></p></div>
```

Thanks for your help anyway!! Note: Hopefully i post this fine here, because i don't know which button is just for html codes to post.

Comment: how is the form submitted

Comment: @Arun by submit, when you click on submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are truly using ajax, as your tags and post suggest, then you can dynamically load the content of your box class upon successful login.

```
$('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function () {
    var formData = $('form').serialize();
    $.post('/login.php', { data: formData }, function () {
        $('.box').html('<div class="box" style="height: 100px;"> <p><img src="/loading.gif" alt="" align="left" /><strong>Logged in...&hellip;</strong></p></div>');
    });
});
```

UPDATE: Because I copy/pasted your html, i had left the display:none attribute on your box html that you wanted to inject.  I removed it and it works great.  I created a simplified JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/qHT3p/.  It is simplified since it doesn't actually perform the $.post but the functionality is essentially the same.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it seems that your code have a error, i get this: SyntaxError: missing } after function body
I did fix that, but it doenst work. 

});

Comment: In what way does it not work?  Are you getting a response from the server?

Comment: Yes, i use firebug console to see if there is a error. He said that } is missing in your code and i did try to add } but it doenst work.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see any syntax errors in the code snippet I posted for you.  Is it possible that you're missing a brace somewhere else?

Comment: It's already okay. I added }); , but i think that my connection is too fast to see that loading image when i am logged in. Do you have a example anywhere of this? Thanks anyway!

Comment: You rocks! That was what i was looking for. Thank you a lot for your code and help!!

Answer (score 0):

To replace an element user [.replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)

```
$('.box').replaceWith('<div class="box" style="display: none; height: 100px;"> <p><img src="/loading.gif" alt="" align="left" /><strong>Logged in...&hellip;</strong></p></div>')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i am looking for a jQuery/Ajax plugin that do check username and password first and if its a succes, then it must show loading image untill you are login.. loading image is for when its a succes, but more for when a user have slow connection. and no, i am not looking for simple jquery loading image, but that do replace a div and shows only loading image when login is a success

Comment: I don't think there is a plugin to do this. You can easily use $.ajax() to do this task

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need ajax,try `jquery.from.js` plugin,you can google it